# Drag and drop image then to database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using drag and drop zone which is work great if it saves to a file on a server, but I want to save it to database, I cant get the image element from code-behind

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";

    string dirFullPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/MediaUploader/");
    string[] files;
    int numFiles;

    files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dirFullPath);
    numFiles = files.Length;
    numFiles = numFiles + 1;

    string str_image = "";

    foreach (string s in context.Request.Files)
    {
        HttpPostedFile file = context.Request.Files[s];
        string fileName = file.FileName;
        string fileExtension = file.ContentType;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
        {
            fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
            str_image = "MyPHOTO_" + numFiles.ToString() + fileExtension;
            string pathToSave = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/MediaUploader/") + str_image;
            file.SaveAs(pathToSave);
        }
    }

    context.Response.Write(str_image);
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything in this code that has anything to do with a database. What do you mean that you can't get the image from the code behind? Is the code posted here not working? I am confused because you said that saving to a file was working but that the problem you are seeing is related to a database. Can you please post the code that is not working.

Comment: im using drop zone which generates an image to preview as HTML tag img 
after been uploading. its possible to save it for a file which i don't want like what wrote above I'm trying to save it in the database which i cant access it as normal asp image!

Comment: is there is way to save an image from handler to db

Comment: why isn't numFiles simply files.Length +1? Why must this be in two steps? Plus, consider the side effects on your method. It'd be better if you passed that as a parameter. This is a good reflex to have otherwise, you're going to have some nasty bugs in the future where you affect your whole system in side-effects at runtime without your knowledge instead of knowing that whenever you explicitely call code with a given set of arguments, those arguments are going to give you always the same results for the same values in input

Answer (score 1):

You can get the bytes that make up the file from file.InputStream by calling file.InputStream.Read into a byte array.  Once you have the bytes you can write them to a database column of type binary.

I like to use base64 strings instead of binary because they are more easily handled for various I/O functions.  Therefore my example below assumes that you are using that methodology.  This is by no means production code but rather just an example that encompases the necessary functionality.

```
    public class DatabaseFile
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// The file name, the database column to which it corresponds is a nvarchar(256)
        /// </summary>
        public string Name = string.Empty;

        /// <summary>
        /// The Mime type of the file, the database column to which it corresponds is a nvarchar(64)
        /// </summary>
        public string Mime = string.Empty;

        /// <summary>
        /// The file data as a base64 string, the database column to which it corresponds is a ntext
        /// </summary>
        public string Data = string.Empty;

        /// <summary>
        /// The file data as a byte array
        /// </summary>
        public byte[] BinaryData
        {
            get { return Convert.FromBase64String(Data); }
            set { Data = Convert.ToBase64String(value); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor to create a DatabaseFile from a HttpPostedFile
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="file"></param>
        public DatabaseFile(HttpPostedFile file)
        {
            Name = file.FileName;
            Mime = file.ContentType;
            byte[] fileBytes = new byte[file.ContentLength];
            file.InputStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, file.ContentLength);
            BinaryData = fileBytes;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Save the file information and data to a database table called [FileTable].
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sqlConnection"></param>
        public void SaveToDatabase(SqlConnection sqlConnection)
        {

            // Parameterized Insert command
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("insert [FileTable] ([Name], [Mime], [Data]) values (@Name, @Mime, @Data)", sqlConnection);

            // Create the necessary parameters
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 256);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Mime", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 64);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Data", SqlDbType.NText);

            // Assign the parameters
            sqlCommand.Parameters["@Name"].Value = Name;
            sqlCommand.Parameters["@Mime"].Value = Mime;
            sqlCommand.Parameters["@Data"].Value = Data;

            // Execute the command
            try
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();
                sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            finally
            {
                sqlConnection.Close();
            }

        }
    }
```

Now in your code within the foreach file loop you would have the following:

```
DatabaseFile dbFile = new DatabaseFile(context.Request.Files[s]);
dbFile.SaveToDatabase(sqlConnection);
```

Comment: can you please drop an example _